# WPF Parent Element Lost Focus

Tags: wpf, focus

I am developing a WPF application. In one of my pages I have a DockPanel with 3 ComboBoxes within it. These 3 ComboBoxes are dependent on each other. So, I have a binding group on the DockPanel and a validation rule for that binding group.

I would like to validate these 3 ComboBoxes when the DockPanel loses focus; however, the DockPanel's LostFocus event is fired when the user clicks on one of the child ComboBoxes within it!

I would have thought that if the child control has focus, the parent control would also have focus...however this does not seem to be the case.

I am looking for a solution to perform validation on the binding group when the DockPanel loses focus...where the focus is lost to a control that is **not** one of its children.

Edit:

So, I created as simple an application as I could to demonstrate the problem.

I have a "FertilizerCombination" class that contains 3 integers that make up the Fertilizer. These must be unique within the application. Currently the only combination that is not available is 10-10-10. This is a hard coded value in the class.

```
Public Class FertilizerCombination
  Private _nitrogen As Integer
  Private _phosphorous As Integer
  Private _potassium As Integer

<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Range(1, 20)> _
Public Property Nitrogen As Integer
    Get
        Return _nitrogen
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.ValidateProperty(value, NitrogenValidationContext)
        _nitrogen = value
    End Set
End Property

<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Range(1, 20)> _
Public Property Phosphorous As Integer
    Get
        Return _phosphorous
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.ValidateProperty(value, PhosphorousValidationContext)
        _phosphorous = value
    End Set
End Property

<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Range(1, 20)> _
Public Property Potassium As Integer
    Get
        Return _potassium
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.ValidateProperty(value, PotassiumValidationContext)
        _potassium = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Sub New()
End Sub
Public Sub New(ByVal nitrogen As Integer, ByVal phosphorous As Integer, ByVal potassium As Integer)
    Me.Nitrogen = nitrogen
    Me.Phosphorous = phosphorous
    Me.Potassium = potassium
End Sub


Public Shared Function FertilizerCombinationAvailable(ByVal nitrogen As Integer, ByVal phosphorous As Integer, ByVal potassium As Integer) As Boolean
    'Checking against combinations already used'
    If nitrogen = "10" And phosphorous = "10" And potassium = "10" Then
        'Combination has already been used'
        Return False
    End If
    'Combination was not used yet'
    Return True
End Function

Public Sub SetFertilizerCombination(ByVal nitrogen As Integer, ByVal phosphorous As Integer, ByVal potassium As Integer)
    System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.ValidateProperty(nitrogen, NitrogenValidationContext)
    System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.ValidateProperty(phosphorous, PhosphorousValidationContext)
    System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.ValidateProperty(potassium, PotassiumValidationContext)
    If FertilizerCombination.FertilizerCombinationAvailable(nitrogen, phosphorous, potassium) = False Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("This fertilizer combination has already been used")
    End If
    Me.Nitrogen = nitrogen
    Me.Phosphorous = phosphorous
    Me.Potassium = potassium
End Sub

Private NitrogenValidationContext = New System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(Me, Nothing, Nothing) With {.MemberName = "Nitrogen"}
Private PhosphorousValidationContext = New System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(Me, Nothing, Nothing) With {.MemberName = "Phosphorous"}
Private PotassiumValidationContext = New System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(Me, Nothing, Nothing) With {.MemberName = "Potassium"}
End Class
```

I have a created a Validation Rule for the Fertilizer Combination Class:

```
Public Class FertilizerCombinationValidationRule
Inherits ValidationRule

Public Overrides Function Validate(ByVal value As Object, ByVal cultureInfo As System.Globalization.CultureInfo) As System.Windows.Controls.ValidationResult
    Dim bg As BindingGroup = TryCast(value, BindingGroup)

    If bg IsNot Nothing AndAlso bg.Items.Count > 0 Then
        'The BindingGroup Items property contains the original object(s)'
        Dim fertilizerCombo As FertilizerCombination = TryCast(bg.Items(0), FertilizerCombination)

        'Using the BindingGroups GetValue method to retrieve the user provided values'
        Dim proposedNitrogen As Integer
        Dim proposedPhosphorous As Integer
        Dim proposedPotassium As Integer
        Try
            proposedNitrogen = bg.GetValue(fertilizerCombo, "Nitrogen")
            proposedPhosphorous = bg.GetValue(fertilizerCombo, "Phosphorous")
            proposedPotassium = bg.GetValue(fertilizerCombo, "Potassium")
            If FertilizerCombination.FertilizerCombinationAvailable(proposedNitrogen, proposedPhosphorous, proposedPotassium) = False Then
                Return New ValidationResult(False, "This fertializer combination has already been used")
            End If
        Catch noValue As System.Windows.Data.ValueUnavailableException
            'a binding was not properly bound yet'
        End Try

    End If
    Return New ValidationResult(True, Nothing)
End Function

End Class
```

I have a "PlantSolution" class that has a FertilizerCombination property. I also have a VM for that class so that it's easy for binding in the XAML:

```
Public Class PlantSolutionVM
  Public Property PlantSolution As PlantSolution
  Public Sub New()
    PlantSolution = New PlantSolution("Produce Blooms", "Using this fertilizer will help your plant produce flowers!", 10, 10, 20)
End Sub
End Class

Public Class PlantSolution

Private _name As String
Private _description As String
Private _fertilizer As FertilizerCombination

<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required()>
Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return _name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.ValidateProperty(value, NameValidationContext)
        _name = value
    End Set
End Property
<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required()>
Public Property Description As String
    Get
        Return _description
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator.ValidateProperty(value, DescriptionValidationContext)
        _description = value
    End Set
End Property
Public ReadOnly Property Fertilizer As FertilizerCombination
    Get
        Return _fertilizer
    End Get
End Property
Public Sub New(name As String, description As String, nitrogen As Integer, phosphorous As Integer, potassium As Integer)
    _fertilizer = New FertilizerCombination(nitrogen, phosphorous, potassium)
    Me.Name = name
    Me.Description = description
End Sub

Private NameValidationContext = New System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(Me, Nothing, Nothing) With {.MemberName = "Name"}
Private DescriptionValidationContext = New System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext(Me, Nothing, Nothing) With {.MemberName = "Description"}
End Class
```

Now here is my XAML for a window called "FunWithFocus":

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="CombinationOptions" Type="sys:Int32" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
            <sys:Int32>0</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>1</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>2</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>3</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>4</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>5</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>6</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>7</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>8</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>9</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>10</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>11</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>12</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>13</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>14</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>15</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>16</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>17</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>18</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>19</sys:Int32>
            <sys:Int32>20</sys:Int32>
        </x:Array>
        <local:PlantSolutionVM x:Key="PlantSolutionVM" />
        <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource PlantSolutionVM}, Path=PlantSolution}" Margin="50">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Solution Name:" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="ItemName" Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Description of Problem:" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="ItemDescription" Text="{Binding Description, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Recommended Fertilizer:" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"/>
        <DockPanel x:Name="FertilizerCombinationContainer" DataContext="{Binding Fertilizer}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <DockPanel.BindingGroup>
                <BindingGroup NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                    <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                        <local:FertilizerCombinationValidationRule />
                    </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                </BindingGroup>
            </DockPanel.BindingGroup>
            <ComboBox x:Name="NitrogenValue" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      ItemsSource="{StaticResource CombinationOptions}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Nitrogen}"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="PhosphorousValue" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      ItemsSource="{StaticResource CombinationOptions}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Phosphorous}"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="PotatssiumValue" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      ItemsSource="{StaticResource CombinationOptions}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Potassium}"/>
        </DockPanel>

        <Button x:Name="SaveIt" Content="Save" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And here is the Code Behind for the page:

```
Class FunWithFocus

Private Sub FertilizerCombinationContainer_Loaded(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles FertilizerCombinationContainer.Loaded
    'FertilizerCombinationContainer.BindingGroup.CancelEdit()'
    'FertilizerCombinationContainer.BindingGroup.BeginEdit()'
End Sub

Private Sub FertilizerCombinationContainer_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles FertilizerCombinationContainer.LostFocus
    'This will get fired if the user drops down one of the comboboxes'
End Sub

'This is how I am currently handling the lost focus...but it doesn't fire if the user clicks somewhere that doesn't take keyboard focus'
'Private Sub FertilizerCombinationContainer_IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles FertilizerCombinationContainer.IsKeyboardFocusWithinChanged'
'    If FertilizerCombinationContainer.IsKeyboardFocusWithin = False Then'
'        FertilizerCombinationContainer.BindingGroup.ValidateWithoutUpdate()'
'        If Validation.GetErrors(FertilizerCombinationContainer).Count = 0 Then'
'            FertilizerCombinationContainer.BindingGroup.CommitEdit()'

'            Dim bg As BindingGroup = FertilizerCombinationContainer.BindingGroup'
'            Dim fertilizerCombo As FertilizerCombination = bg.Items(0)'
'            Dim proposedNitrogen As Integer'
'            Dim proposedPhosphorous As Integer'
'            Dim proposedPotassium As Integer'
'            Try'
'                proposedNitrogen = bg.GetValue(fertilizerCombo, "Nitrogen")'
'                proposedPhosphorous = bg.GetValue(fertilizerCombo, "Phosphorous")'
'                proposedPotassium = bg.GetValue(fertilizerCombo, "Potassium")'
'                ''there was a change: set it'
'                fertilizerCombo.SetFertilizerCombination(proposedNitrogen, proposedPhosphorous, proposedPotassium)'
'            Catch noValue As System.Windows.Data.ValueUnavailableException'
'                ''a binding was not properly bound yet'
'            End Try'
'        End If'
'    End If'

'End Sub'



End Class
```

If you put a break point on the method that handles FertilizerCombinationContainer's LostFocus event, you will notice that it is fired when you select one of the ComboBoxes even though it is a child of the FertilizerContainer element.

Thank you,

-Frinny

Comment: Offering your xaml source would be helpful.

Comment: Take a look at the [`FrameworkElement.IsKeyboardFocusWithin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.uielement.iskeyboardfocuswithin.aspx)property.

Comment: Thanks HighCore, that is what I am currently using however I didn't feel it was 100% right.

Comment: I posted code from an example project that you can use to try it out for yourself

Comment: The reason I'm not 100% happy with the IsKeyboardFocusWithin property is because if I click somewhere that doesn't take Keyboard Focus (ie, the window itself) then the validation doesn't get executed...I would like it to though

Comment: IsKeyboardFocusWithin  worked perfectly for me, you can't click away to just anywhere, but as long as you are clicking on focusable element it works like a charm. Thank you @federico-berasategui